Allow user to map domain to my domain on web platform using CNAME
I have been googling about "how web platform allow mapping of custom domain to their web platform" like what netlify.com or vercel.com is doing and provide SSL certificates also.
I have a web platform and I want to add this feature. My domain ( mydomain.com ) is on Cloudflare and the apps are proxied through it ( because I want to use cloudflare CDN). For example - A user who has created the app is pointed to user.mydomain.com
I want to allow this users to attach custom domains to their platform ( like otherdomain.com points to user.mydomain.com using CNAME and provide free SSL cert. Would nginx/caddy/openrusty be of help.
